# Linux shell create background process -- ls & doesn't return to prompt, require Enter pressed

Tags: linux, shell, process, background, ls

I am learning to create background processes in Linux (or MacOS) shell. Most of the commands run as expected -- they return the prompt after running the command `$<command> &`, e.g. `$top &`, `$man ls &`, etc.

However, I have a problem with the command ls: executing `$ls &` does not return to the prompt immediately as others but it requires me to press Enter to come back the prompt.

How can I explain this? Thanks.

Comment: I guess `ls` put some of its output in your prompt, looks like it does not return.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you see something likes

```
$ ls &
[1] 23682
$ bin/   dev/  home/      initrd.img.old@  lib32/  lost+found/  mnt/  proc/  run/   selinux/  sys/  usr@  vmlinuz@
boot/  etc/  initrd.img@  lib/         lib64/  media/   opt/  root/  sbin/  srv/      tmp/  var/  vmlinuz.old@
```

At this moment, `ls` already returned. Note that `$` in the third line, which is the prompt of my shell. Because you put `ls` to run on the background, some of its output be put to after the shell prompt by the shell, this makes it looks like that `ls` has not returned.